# Combine attribute and zoom based style in GeoServer using CSS styling

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

Is it possible to use attribute and zoom based condition to apply CSS style in GeoServer? I have a point layer, I would like to use attribute and zoom  based condition to apply a colour style and sizes at different zoom levels. I have tried different code combinations but not been successful. Below is my latest attempt but the style is not applied.

```
* {
    label: [No];
    mark: symbol(circle);
   
      :mark {
     [@sd >0][@sd <=6000]{  mark-size: 50m;    font-size: 25;};
     [@sd > 6000] [@sd <= 12000]{    mark-size: 25px;    font-size: 25;};
     [@sd >12000] [@sd <= 24000]{    mark-size: 50px;    font-size: 25;};
     [@sd >24000] [@sd <= 48000]{    mark-size: 750px;    font-size: 25;};

    [Km > 245] [Km <= 295]  { fill: blue;};
    [Km > 295] [Km <= 345]  { fill: pink;};
    [Km > 345] [Km <= 395]  { fill: yellow;};
    [Km > 395]              { fill: orange;};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staying close to your current attempt, this seems to work:

```
* {
    label: [No];
    mark: symbol(circle);
   
    [@sd >0][@sd <=6000]{  mark-size: 50m;    font-size: 25;};
    [@sd > 6000] [@sd <= 12000]{    mark-size: 25px;    font-size: 25;};
    [@sd >12000] [@sd <= 24000]{    mark-size: 50px;    font-size: 25;};
    [@sd >24000] [@sd <= 48000]{    mark-size: 750px;    font-size: 25;};

    [Km > 245] [Km <= 295]  { :mark{ fill: blue} };
    [Km > 295] [Km <= 345]  { :mark{ mark-fill: pink }};
    [Km > 345] [Km <= 395]  { :mark{ mark-fill: yellow }};
    [Km > 395]              { :mark{ mark-fill: orange }};
  
}
```

That is, do not use the `:mark` pseudo-selector as a container for other rules.

That said, the style still seems a bit too much work... something similar seems simpler and would result in a more progressive display:

```
* {
    label: [No];
    font-size: 25;

    mark: symbol(circle);
    mark-size: Interpolate(@sd, 6000, 25, 120000, 50, 24000, 750);

    :mark [Km > 245] {
       fill: Categorize(Km, blue, 295, pink, 345, yellow, 395, orange);
    }   

  
}
```

(it's not clear what output you want for Km <= 245, the style currently produces gray fill below that value since the the mark driver property is still enabled)

Comment: The Km column contains numbers 247 : 423 which I want to use to categorize. Your answer has pointed me in the right direction, the manual/documentation.

Comment: The interpolate does not accept units so I will modify the answer so that I can use units in the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455754/combine-attribute-and-zoom-based-style-in-geoserver-using-css-styling/455757#455757) posted by [@Andrea Aime](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2831/andrea-aime) above was helpful and i have accepted it. Made a few modifications to suit my use case. The Interpolate function was not suitable because I wanted to add unit for the sizes. Below is my own working code.

```
* {
    label: [No];
    mark: symbol(circle);
    :mark  {
       fill: [categorize(Km ,  '#00FF00', 295, '#FFFACD', 345, '#F08080', 395, '#000000')];}
}
 [@sd >0][@sd <=6000]{
    mark-size: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;}
 [@sd > 6000] [@sd <= 12000]{
    mark-size: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;}
 [@sd >12000] [@sd <= 24000]{
    mark-size: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;}
 [@sd >24000] [@sd <= 48000]{
    mark-size: 75px;
    font-size: 25px;}
```